# How to create a library to be used by composer autoloading?

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to make [this package](https://github.com/simkimsia/webbot) to be autoloaded by Composer.

This package is available on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/simkimsia/webbot)

I realized I need to add something to `composer.json` and I need to have a `autoload.php` somewhere.

The only class that should be autoloaded is the `Webbot.php`.

Can someone give me the step by step breakdown to accomplish this?

Google search results returned are instructions to autoload libraries.

I need instructions on how to write autoloadable libraries.

Comment: Do you want to publish this onto Packagist for others to use, or do you just want to make it work on your own projects?

Comment: Take a look at the note at the bottom of this [doc](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading). It says you can include `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php` files and modify associative arrays they return to configure your own autoloader.

Comment: I am answering Chris question on behalf of questioner. He is my brother and I am guiding him a bit on how to use SO. Publish this onto Packagist for all to use.

Comment: @GuzAlexander Which doc?

Comment: @KimStacks There is a link on the wordl `doc` in my previous comment.

Comment: @GuzAlexander ohhhhhh. it was not obvious. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

First, you need to have your package structured in either PSR-0 or PSR-4. I haven't started using PSR-4 yet as it has only just been accepted as a standard. Composer will still support PSR-0 for a long time to come.

This means that you MUST follow these rules:

- A fully-qualified namespace and class must have the following
  structure `<Vendor Name>\(<Namespace>\)*<Class Name>`
- Each namespace must have a top-level namespace ("Vendor Name").
- Each namespace can have as many sub-namespaces as it wishes.
- Each namespace separator is converted to a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR when
  loading from the file system.
- Each _ character in the CLASS NAME is converted to a
  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. The _ character has no special meaning in the
  namespace.
- The fully-qualified namespace and class is suffixed with .php when
  loading from the file system.
- Alphabetic characters in vendor names, namespaces, and class names
  may be of any combination of lower case and upper case.

[Full FIG guidelines here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)

This would mean that your package should be laid out in your github repository as follows:

```
-src
    -Simkimsia
        -Webbot
            -Webbot.php
-composer.json
-license.md
-{any other base level files}
```

Webbot.php would be in the namespace : `Simkimsia\Webbot` as dicated by the directory structure.

Then... As this is a github package, you can add it to your projects composer.json using the repositories property.

```
{
    "name" : 'test',
    "description" : 'Test',
    "keywords" : ['test'],
    "repositories" : [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/simkimsia/webbot.git"
    }
    ],
    "require" : {
        "simkimsia/webbot" : "dev-master"
    }
}
```

The package will be available from Composers autoload and can be instantiated as :

```
$webbot = new Simkimsia\Webbot\Webbot();
```

**Note:**
Composers autoload.php will be available in once you have run `composer install`:

```
/vendor/composer/autoload.php
```

Just include this file at the start of your PHP script and your classes will be available.

Comment: I wonder how to fill in the "require" section properly? I have repo at gitlab, like "username/reponame", and I have all my classes under "src/MyVendorName/MyLibName/" -- shat should I write into "require"? "username/reponame" -or- "myvendorname/mylibname"?

Comment: Always vendor/libname it's a PSR-1/PSR-4 auto loader so follows a tight specification.

Comment: To make it more distinctive, my choices are: "repo_username/repo_name" -or- "myvendorname/mylibname"?