# How to publish package and installing with composer php

Tags: php, composer-php

I have so far been able to publish my package on packagist.
From my repository, http://github.com/pbalan/directory-parser

I followed [How to create a library to be used by composer autoloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137019/how-to-create-a-library-to-be-used-by-composer-autoloading)

When I try to install the same using composer, I am unable to do so.
Composer fails saying:

```
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Reading composer.json of pbalan/directory-parser (0.0.1)
 Importing tag 0.0.1 (0.0.1.0)
 Reading composer.json of pbalan/directory-parser (master)
 Importing branch master (dev-master)
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
  - The requested package pbalan/directory-parser 1.0.0 could not be found.

 Potential causes:
  - A typo in the package name
  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
```

Here's my composer I have in my github repository:

```
 {
    "name" : "pbalan/directory-parser",
    "description" : "DirectoryParser",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords" : ["DirectoryParser"],
    "homepage" : "https://github.com/pbalan/directory-parser",
    "authors" : [
    {
    "name" : "prashant"
    }
    ],
    "autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {"src" : ""}
    },
    "require" : {
    "php": ">=5.3.3"
    }
 }
```

And I am trying to install in a fresh directory using this composer.json:

```
 {
   "name" : "pbalan/directory-parser",
   "description" : "DirectoryParser",
   "license": "MIT",
   "keywords" : ["DirectoryParser"],
   "homepage" : "https://github.com/pbalan/directory-parser",
   "authors" : [
    {
        "name" : "prashant"
    }
   ],
   "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://github.com/pbalan/directory-parser.git"
    }
       ],
   "require" : {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "pbalan/directory-parser": "dev-master"
    }
 }
```

I changed my composer.json now to a point where I have no errors, however I am not able to install the package and just install autoloader files.

How could I get my package installed?
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are re-using the name of your package in the second `composer.json`.

Simply use this as the `composer.json` for your empty directory:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "pbalan/directory-parser": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

That's all! You don't need all the extra information such as name, description etc. unless you are creating another library that should be available on Packagist as well.